# How do I detect when edits have begun in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I want to enable buttons (Cancel, Save etc) when edits have begun on an entity. I don't want to add code to every property. **Is there an event that fires the moment an entity is "dirty"?**

I'm using database first EF with the designer and WPF controls bound directly to entity properties via the data context (CollectionViewSource).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Self Tracking Entities template to generate the entities from the EDMX, you can check the ChangeTracker status, and these also implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so you can listen to that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407090(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar with Self Tracking Entities. It looks like a significant change to the structure of my already built WPF application which I'm reluctant to do. Using INotifyPropertyChanged it appears that I would still need to code every property to detect when edits have begun on an entity. Thanks for the info & link.

Comment: Nope, using INotifyPropertyChanged you can subscribe a single time for each entity and whenever it occurs you check for the ChangeTracker status, the properties are auto generated by the T4 based on the EDMX and raise the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning that you can change the T4 template to generate any code you need inside the setters for every property and stuff like that. If you're not familiar with T4, I Suggest you read up on this a little and get the T4 Tangible editor, which simplifies the edition of T4 a whole lot.

Comment: They won't help you. In WPF the TextBox defaults to UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, which means it is possible for the underlying value to be unchanged, whilst the control value (.Text) has changed ... AFAIK This is a limitation of WPF Binding design.

Comment: @Jack WHAT? First of all what you're saying has absolutely NOTHING to do with what the OP is asking for. Second, it's not a "limitation", is a by-design default behavior which is easily modifiable by changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to something else, such as `PropertyChanged`. Third, this answer dates back to one month ago, so I can't understand why you're commenting here.

Comment: To clarify: in WPF there are 2 levels of Dirty, the Source can be dirty (in this case an Entity) and the Target can be dirty (the TextBox.Text property). The user's concept of dirty is "have I changed anything on screen" which is Source.IsDirty || View.IsDirty. The WPF Binding is perfectly placed to surface IsDirty but it does not. The end result is that whilst the focus is in a TextBox (OP's "edits have begun") the Cancel and Save buttons will incorrectly be Disabled. This is a design flaw in WPF and is not easy to workaround.

Comment: @Jack `"design flaw", "not easy to workaround"` - why not just `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` ?? - how do you propose to design a UI technology with such binding capabilities that doesn't have the supposed limitation you're talking about? - Also, if you don't like to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` for every binding, you can easily avoid that by using an `Attached Property`. I did that myself in my own WPF framework. So I don't see where the supposed design flaw is.